# Media Foundation: Getting a MediaSink from a SinkWriter

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to add an MP4 file sink to a Topology. When my `MediaSource` is already MP4, I use `MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink` and `MF_MPEG4SINK_SPSPPS_PASSTHROUGH`. When my `MediaSource` isn't MP4 (so raw YUV from a webcam), I want to use `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL` so that I don't have to figure out MP4 headers and other complex stuff.

According to [the MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374649(v=vs.85).aspx) I should be able to use `GetServiceForStream` to get at the `MediaSink`, since the input type is different from the output type. However it always returns `MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_SERVICE`.

How can I get the underlying `MediaSink` out of a `MediaSinkWriter`?

Alternatively, how can I easily create a MP4 media sink for an arbitrary topology?

```
HRESULT CreateVideoFileSink(
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSourceSD,     // Pointer to the stream descriptor.
    LPCWSTR pFilename,                  // Name of file to save to.
    IMFStreamSink **ppStream)           // Receives a pointer to the stream sink.
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pAttr;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaTypeHandler> pHandler;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> pType;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaSink> pSink;
    CComPtr<IMFStreamSink> pStream;
    CComPtr<IMFSinkWriter> pSinkWriter;
    CComPtr<IMFByteStream> pByteStream;

    *ppStream = nullptr;

    // Get the media type handler for the stream.
    IFR(pSourceSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler));

    // Get the major media type.
    GUID guidMajorType;
    IFR(pHandler->GetMajorType(&guidMajorType));

    IFR(MFCreateAttributes(&pAttr, 1));
    IFR(pAttr->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, TRUE));

    // Create an output file 
    if (MFMediaType_Video == guidMajorType)
    {
        GUID guidSubType;
        IFR(pHandler->GetCurrentMediaType(&pType));
        IFR(pType->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &guidSubType));

        if (MFVideoFormat_H264 == guidSubType)
        {
            // ... use MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink
        }
        else
        {
            IFR(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(pFilename, nullptr, pAttr, &pSinkWriter));
            DWORD streamIdx;
            IFR(pSinkWriter->AddStream(pType, &streamIdx));
            IFR(pSinkWriter->GetServiceForStream(MF_SINK_WRITER_MEDIASINK, GUID_NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSink)));
            IFR(pSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(streamIdx, &pStream));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Don't use this stream
        IFR(E_FAIL)
    }

    // Return IMFStreamSink pointer to caller.
    *ppStream = pStream.Detach();

    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out right after writing the question - of course. The `SinkWriter` doesn't *have* a `MediaSink` until you call `BeginWriting`.

```
IFR(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(pFilename, nullptr, pAttr, &pSinkWriter));
DWORD streamIdx;
IFR(pSinkWriter->AddStream(pType, &streamIdx));
IFR(pSinkWriter->BeginWriting()); // <<----
IFR(pSinkWriter->GetServiceForStream(MF_SINK_WRITER_MEDIASINK, GUID_NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSink)));
IFR(pSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(streamIdx, &pStream));
```

(Make sure you don't let the `SinkWriter` get Released while you're using the `StreamSink`)